# How to change Icon size in the TabLayout

Tags: android

I use viewpager and Tablayout to implement tab fragment then I setIcon on the tab but the icons are too small. I looking for the solutions a day. setup style
custom tab  etc...   I try to build custom tab but it always break down. Any idea?

Here is my Code

```
     viewPager= (ViewPager)findViewById(R.id.viewPager);
    viewPager.setAdapter(newCustomAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager(),getApplicationContext()));
    tabLayout=(TabLayout)findViewById(R.id.tabLayout);


   Toolbar mytoolbar= (Toolbar)findViewById(R.id.my_toolbar);
    mytoolbar.setTitleTextColor(Color.WHITE);
    setSupportActionBar(mytoolbar);

    getSupportActionBar().setTitle(R.string.mytitle);

    tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);
    tabLayout.getTabAt(0).setIcon(R.drawable.ic);
    tabLayout.getTabAt(1).setIcon(R.drawable.taichung);
    tabLayout.getTabAt(2).setIcon(R.drawable.ic);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
protected void changeTabs(TabLayout tabLayout) {
        Logger.print("In change tab font");
        ViewGroup vg = (ViewGroup) tabLayout.getChildAt(0);
        int tabsCount = vg.getChildCount();
        Logger.print("Tab count--->"+tabsCount);
        for (int j = 0; j < tabsCount; j++) {
            ViewGroup vgTab = (ViewGroup) vg.getChildAt(j);
            int tabChildsCount = vgTab.getChildCount();
            for (int i = 0; i < tabChildsCount; i++) {
                View tabViewChild = vgTab.getChildAt(i);
                if (tabViewChild instanceof AppCompatTextView) {
                    ImageView viewChild = (ImageView) tabViewChild;
                    //Now do whatever you want with viewChild

                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: I am trying it now

Comment: Which part changes the Icon size?

Comment: You get the imageview as viewChild,Then you can change the icon size programatically

Comment: I past it in to my code but it does not change anything . And is that  Textview in (TextView) tabViewChild;  Imageview?  It shows the redline under the code

Comment: Edited.This will not change the code.You will get the reference of image,then you have to change it dynamically

Comment: very Hard to understand. Anyway i figure out later

Comment: I find out the answer.If i try to use "setupWithViewPager" the program will set the icon size for me automatically  so i have to customize myself

Comment: how AppCompatTextView is ImageView ? i don't understand